# jspdf is coloring the first row and header

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I am trying to color only the first row , It is working well but the problem it is coloring the header also in the same time,
Do anyone has an idea?
I am using jspdf
This is the snippet code

```
if (new Date(tableaudate[0]).getDay() === 0) {
          if (data.row.index === 0) {
            data.cell.styles.fillColor = [211, 211, 211];
            console.log(data);
          }
        }
```

I have added this piece of code after in order to overwrite any style but it is not working :

```
options.headStyles = {
      fillColor: [23, 55, 100],
      textColor: '#FFFFFF',
      minCellHeight: 8,
      fontSize: 8
    };
```

It is applying the style of the first row in the header.
Please do anyone has an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem comes that head and body have same index so to distinct this is the solution :
added this piece of code

```
&& data.row.section !== 'head'


 if (new Date(tableaudate[0]).getDay() === 0) {
          if (data.row.index === 0 && data.row.section !== 'head') {
            data.cell.styles.fillColor = [211, 211, 211];
          }
        }
```